# Rails created_at timestamp order disagrees with id order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 2.3.5 app with a table containing id and created_at columns.  The table records state changes to entities over time, so I occasionally use it to look up the state of an entity at a particular time, by looking for state changes that occurred before the time, and picking the latest one according to the created_at timestamp.
For 10 out of 1445 entities, the timestamps of the state changes are in a different order to the ids, and the state of the last state change differs from the state which is stored with the entity itself, e.g.

```
  id  |     created_at      | entity_id | state |
------+---------------------+-----------+-------+
 1151 | 2009-01-26 10:27:02 | 219       | 1     | 
 1152 | 2009-01-26 10:27:11 | 219       | 2     | 
 1153 | 2009-01-26 10:27:17 | 219       | 4     | 
 1154 | 2009-01-26 10:26:41 | 219       | 5     |
```

I can probably get around this by ordering on id instead of timestamp, but can't think of an explanation as to how it could have happened.  The app uses several mongrel instances, but they're all on the same machine (Debian Lenny); am I missing something obvious?  DB is Postgres.

Answer (score 5):

Because Rails is using [database sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-sequence.html) to fetch the new id for your `id` field (at least in PostgreSQL) on [insert](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter.html#method-i-insert) or with the [`RETURNING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-insert.html) keyword if the database supports it.

But it updates the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields on create with [`ActiveRecord::Timestamp#create_with_timestamps`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html) method which uses the system time.

The row `1154` was inserted later, but the timestamp for `created_at` field was calculated before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I'm still confused as to how this could happen - I mean the timestamp for 1154 is earlier than the rest by at least 21s, yet its id, and the current state of the entity (5) suggest it came last in the sequence.

Comment: @Leo Did you have a good explanation for this? `1154` really came last in the order?